# webpack-dev-server not reloading HTML

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

The CSS is being updated when changed with HotModuleReplacement, however, I have to reload the page in order to see HTML changes:

```
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
},
```